# clang-tidy emits warning when compiling with c++20 enabled

Tags: c++, c++20, clang-tidy

I recently updated my project and its CI pipelines to use C++20 features. When I changed the compiler settings to use C++20, clang-tidy started to emit the following warning (I treat them as errors) for all my checked files:

```
error: invalid case style for template parameter 'expr-type' [readability-identifier-naming,-warnings-as-errors]
```

I could narrow it down to the following minimal example using CMake and a clang-tidy config file:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(clang_tidy_warning LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(clang_tidy_warning main.cpp)
```

**.clang-tidy**

```
Checks: >
  readability-*,

WarningsAsErrors: '*'

CheckOptions:
  - {key: readability-identifier-naming.TemplateParameterCase,           value: lower_case}
  - {key: readability-identifier-naming.TypeTemplateParameterCase,       value: CamelCase }
  - {key: readability-identifier-naming.TemplateParameterPrefix,         value: t_ }
  - {key: readability-identifier-naming.TypeTemplateParameterPrefix,     value: T_ }
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() { return 0; }
```

You should be able to reproduce it in Ubuntu 20.04 with the following commands starting in the root directory:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG ..
run-clang-tidy-12  -quiet
```

The error/warning disappears if you do one of the following things:

- remove the specified check options from the config file
- set the c++ standard to 17
- remove the `#include` in the main file

Exchanging `iostream` with another standard library header didn't help, but I have not tested them all. It is also worth mentioning that all other possible clang-tidy configuration options do not cause this error. I had nearly all of them in the original config file and removed the ones that do not cause the error. It seems like only the `TemplateParameter` and `TypeTemplateParameter` suboptions are affected by this. I have tested clang-tidy versions 9, 10, and 12. All emit the same warning. I also tested passing different compilers (clang 12 and gcc10) to CMake. Did not change anything (do not know if clang-tidy is even affected by the compiler choice, I guess not). I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (up-to-date) and you can also reproduce the error in a GitHub action runner.

So my questions are. Is this a (known) bug or is there any incompatibility with C++ 20 in this clang-tidy setup? If it is already known, can you give me an explanation of why it occurs and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

As Lawrence Benson mentioned in the comments, this might be also OS-related. He couldn't reproduce on a Mac, but on Ubuntu.

**Related bug report**

Here is the link to a related bug report found by 0x5453: [click me](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46752)

Update: As "Buster" pointed out in the comments, the bug report has been moved
[here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/46097)

Comment: FWIW I cannot reproduce on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zbac34qb8) with the latest clang-tidy, so could be a bug in version 12.

Comment: Possibly related: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46752

Comment: @0x5453 seems to be the same problem. I think I might add a comment there to link this question (if I find the time). The example I posted might help to track down the bug if it isn't already solved (as you mentioned in your first comment). Good news for me is, that I just have to wait for the new version to be available in Ubuntus package manager.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem at the moment with clang-tidy-10. This might also be related to the OS. On my MacBook, I don't get any errors but in GitHub Actions I get `error: invalid case style for type template parameter 'expr-type'`. So maybe this is a problem of the Ubuntu version, as brew llvm seems to be fine.

Comment: @LawrenceBenson Thank you for the input. I added the info from your comment to the question. I finally managed to request an account on bugzilla. As soon as it gets activated, I will link this question in the bug report shared by 0x5453. I hope it will help to track down and fix the bug soon

Comment: @wychmaster I just double checked and brew must have updated at some point. On my MacBook, I have clang-tidy from LLVM 11.1.0 running, whereas GitHub Actions is running on clang-tidy-10. I bumped GitHub Actions to clang-tidy-11 and then -12 but the problem still remains. So this is definitely not only a 12 bug, but also in 10 and 11 on Ubuntu.

Comment: I reproduced the problem with LLVM 13

Comment: I wonder if something like  `readability-identifier-naming.TypeTemplateParameterIgnoredRegexp` can be used to workaround this

Comment: Recent comments on the related bug are at https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/46097 (LLVM Bugzilla is now read-only)

Comment: @Buster Thanks for the link. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is still not fixed in version 14.

However, as "Schrodinger ZHU" already hinted in the question comments and as shown by the user "saitou1024" in the [bug report on Github](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/46097), one can use `readability-identifier-naming.TypeTemplateParameterIgnoredRegexp` to work around this problem.

Add the following line under `CheckOptions` to your clang-tidy configuration file:

```
CheckOptions:  
  - {key: readability-identifier-naming.TypeTemplateParameterIgnoredRegexp, value: expr-type}
```

For me, this fixed the issue and I can now treat `readability-identifier-naming` warnings as errors again to enforce naming conventions in a CI pipeline.

**Additional note:**

Since the line above only affects the `TypeTemplateParameter` options and the bug also occurred when `TemplateParameter` options were specified, note that [there is also a `TemplateParameterIgnoredRegexp`](https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/readability-identifier-naming.html#cmdoption-arg-templateparameterignoredregexp) option. So in case this workaround doesn't fix the problem for you, try adding the same line using `TemplateParameterIgnoredRegexp`.